# Sort an array using generic functions throws error on closure result type

Tags: swift, generics, set, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a generic function to filter an array using a FilterDescriptor(similar to SortDescriptors described in this post: http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/sort-descriptors-in-swift/).
Basically the filtered elements should be in any of the sets to be included in the filter. I'm following this approach because the filters need to be selected at runtime, and you can have a combinations of them.

However I'm getting this errors when constructing the filterFunction():

> error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to closure result type '_'
>
> case .grade: return filterDescriptor(key: { $0.grade }, set: gradeFilters)
>
> error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to closure result type '_'
>
> case .term: return filterDescriptor(key: { $0.term }, set: termFilters)

This is my code:

```
struct Note {
    let grade: String
    let term: Int
}

typealias FilterDescriptor<Value> = (Value) -> Bool

class Filter {

    var gradeFilters: Set<String> = []
    var termFilters: Set<Int> = []

    enum Option: Int {
        case grade, term

        private func filterDescriptor<Value, Key>(
            key: @escaping (Value) -> Key,
            set: Set<Key>)
            -> FilterDescriptor<Value> {
            return { set.contains(key($0)) }
        }

        func filterFunction() -> FilterDescriptor<Note> {
            switch self {
                case .grade: return filterDescriptor(key: { $0.grade }, set: gradeFilters)
                case .term: return filterDescriptor(key: { $0.term }, set: termFilters)
            }
        }
    }
}

let notes = [Note(grade: "F grade", term: 10), Note(grade: "A grade", term: 3)]
// Filter by grade
let filter = Filter.Option.grade.filterFunction()
let filteredNotes = notes.filter(filter)
```

I think is related to the Set<Key> parameter in filterDescriptor method and the error messages aren't helping

Comment: Yup, the error messages definately aren't helping (they're better in Xcode 9). The problem is simply that an `Option` instance doesn't have access to `gradeFilters` and `termFilters`. Those are stored instance properties of `Filter`, not `Filter.Option` (enums can't have stored instance properties anyway).

Comment: In Swift types nested in other types (in your case, the `Option` enum that is declared inside the `Filter` class) are not bound to an instance of the outside class and hence they don't have access to the instance properties of the outside class either. Hence, `filterFunction` cannot access `gradeFilters` or `termFilters`.